# (Discord.js) I wanna send a message on channel before the bot goes offline

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've trying this:

```
if(message.content == config.goesOff){
client.channels.fetch(channelId.toString()).then(channel => {
    channel.send("The bot is shutting down").then(()=>{server.close()});
});

server.close();

return
```

}

But when I use the command !fbOff (config.goesOff) it don't send the message "The bot is shutting down", it just run the

```
    Sever.close()
```

Comment: Can you log channel to see if its a valid channel object or not?

Comment: yes it's a valid channel object

Comment: Consider checking if `message.content` does indeed equal to `config.goesOff`? It may not be triggered in the first place. Also, why do you have `server.close();` outside of your if statement as well?

Comment: yeah, the server close fine, my problem is that isn't sending my message, it simply closes and ignore message, so if I comment the line of server.close() the message is sent well

Comment: I think its not triggering the if statement. so it just triggers the `server.close()` that is outside the if statement. Remove the `server.close()` from outside, and see if that if message is triggered.

Comment: I've tried it before, but it also don't works :(

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
const channel = await client.channels.fetch(channelId.toString())
await channel.send("The bot is shutting down")
server.close();
```

Make sure your message event is async :)